# How to develop role based workflow in SharePoint Server?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, moss, infopath2010

How to develop role based workflow with InfoPath form in SharePoint Server 2010?

There are three roles:
user1 - this user creates request form
user2 - this user verifies and Approve/Reject form if user Approves mail will sent to user3.
user3

How to develop this type of workflow?
Please explain sharepoint designer workflow actions?

Answer (score 0):

The exact steps, of course, will depend on what precisely you're trying to accomplish. Based on what I've read, and the tags on the question, it would appear that you want:

- An InfoPath request form (created by a certain kind of user)
- An approval process for that form
- Someone to be notified when the approval is completed

Your exact needs could considerably change how this works; for example, do you need the approval to happen on the form itself? e.g. I can click the filled in Request form as an approver and then click Approve or Deny

Or do you need the basic SharePoint approval? I'm operating under this assumption.

To accomplish this you can have your InfoPath form submit to a library and have a workflow run when an item is created. This workflow then starts an approval process. When complete, use the send email action to notify the group that needs to be notified.

Again, more information can net a more complete solution, but this should get you started down the right track.

Comment: exact •An InfoPath request form (created by a certain kind of user) •An approval process for that form •Someone to be notified when the approval is completed Above telling exact things is corret Please give me the solution means Steps how to develop role base workflow